# Как удалённо дебажить web страницу в chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, отладка

Есть raspberry pi 3 с установленным raspbian (Debian), на нём открыта web страница через google chrome.

Возможно ли удалённо, на ПК(windows 10), просматривать лог javascript? И желательно бы ещё просмотр элементом, как при подключении adnroid устройства через usb: [Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: В тексте вопросов можно использовать синтаксис разметки [Markdown](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), с ним например ссылки гораздо проще делаются. Посмотрите как это в коде вашего вопроса выглядит: [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся панель инструментов для разработчика гугл хрома - на самом деле просто HTML страница, которая работает с самим браузером используя WebSocket протокол.

Для того, чтобы гугл хром запустил веб сервер с инструментом разработчиков, его нужно запустить с параметром --remote-debugging-port=ПОРТ . При этом гугл хром запускает веб сервер который слшуает только локалхост ( 127.0.0.1 ) . Как вариант - это ssh port forwarding или другой любой вариант для port forwarding ( iptables ).

Вариант с SSH port forwarding: ssh -L 8080:localhost:ПОРТ хост

Более подробно можно прочитать [по этой ссылке](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol)

*Внимание: Это не работает, если браузер уже запущен. При запуске гугл хрома с этим параметром, когда он уже работает, произойдет ровно ничего. Это связано с тем как работает сам гугл хром. Один из вариантов это поменять рабочую папку браузера на другую.*

Comment: То есть, на малине нужно запустить хром с аргументам "remote-debugging-port", настроить sh port forwarding и потом с ПК заходить по ip адресу малины + порт который указал в аргументе?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли.